# Multiple tabs application with react

Tags: reactjs, tabs

Good afternoon, I need a service desk type application with the ability to open tickets in different tabs. 1st way - We can use split screen in one browser tab, i.e. on the left there will be a list of tickets, and on the right there will be tickets opened by clicking from the list, and each click opens a new tab with a ticket. Or 2nd way - we can use browser tabs and open a new browser tab each time.
The historicity of the transitions within the tabs should also be maintained, since each ticket can be linked to others and we must be able to navigate between them in each separate tab.
What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a design system (or be inspired by) to implement de tab UI: [Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/), [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/), and many others. And integrate this with [React-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) that can gives you the history.

Comment: this history will be for the whole application, but I need a history separately for each tab

Comment: Take a look at [history library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history). I never used, but I think you can give it a try.